# Capturar datos de un select que esta fuera de etiqueta form method="post"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Buenas tardes quería preguntar si es posible capturar datos de un input o cualquier otra etiqueta que este fuera de

este es el caso:

```
    <select id="my-select" asp-for="ListaIntegrantes" multiple="multiple" width:98% margin:10px">

    @foreach (var item in services.GetCarreras())
    {
        <optgroup label="@item.Nombre"></optgroup>
        {
            foreach (var itemD in services.GeTDocentess().Where(x => x.IdDivision == item.Id))
            {
                <option id="ipp" value="@itemD.NumeroControl">

                    @itemD.Nombre

                </option>
            }
        }
    }

</select>

<form method="post">

    <label class="col-2">Nombre:</label>
    <input class="col-10" asp-for="Nombre" type="text" required="required" />

    <label class="col-2">Encargado del Cuerpo:</label>
    <input class="col-10" asp-for="Lider" type="text" required />

    <label class="col-2">Descripcion:</label>
    <input class="col-10" asp-for="Descripcion" type="text" required />

    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <a href="~/Cuerpos" class="btn">Cancelar</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Agregar" />
</form>
```

Quisiera que el controlador que recibe la información de lo que esta en el form también recibiera información fuera del form, lo que pasa es que cuando meto el select dentro del form todos los items del select se muestran mal.
Gracias!!

Comment: Realmente el *select* debería estar dentro del *form*; no veo nada que justifique que haya un problema con eso. ¿Podrías mostrar qué pasa cuando pones el select dentro del *form* (por ejemplo añadiendo el HTML generado)?